# Failed to generate client for class interface ExampleRestClient : Sub resource type is not a class: io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-rest-client, quarkus-reactive

After adding a Uni method to the `ExampleRestClient`, whenever I run the application locally and hit a route that uses the RestClient, I get these errors:

`Request failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error injecting com.example.client.ExampleRestClient com.example.services.BookService.exampleRestClient`

`Failed to generate client for class interface com.fanthreesixty.audience.client.ExampleRestClient : Sub resource type is not a class: io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni`

- I am using quarkus `v2.16.6.Final`
- I am using the `quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson` extension for the rest client which according to my research, supports both Uni and blocking.

EXAMPLE REST CLIENT:

```
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;

@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "example-core")
@RegisterClientHeaders(ExampleClientHeader.class)
@ApplicationScoped
public interface ExampleRestClient {

    @GET
    @Path("/author/{authorId}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @CacheResult(cacheName = "author")
    Author getAuthor(@RestPath String authorId);

    @GET
    @Path("/books/{bookId}/page-ids")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    Uni<Set<UUID>> getBookPagesIds(@RestPath String bookId);

    @GET
    @Path("/books/{bookId}/page-ids")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    Set<UUID> getBookPagesIdsBlocked(@RestPath String orgId);
}
```

I have many similar methods to `getAuthor` in this Interface but I did not include them to avoid redundancy.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the issue?

Attempts:

- I had both `quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson` and `quarkus-rest-client-reactive` so i removed the second one but still faced the same error.
- After removing `quarkus-rest-client-reactive`, it was still showing up in the External Libraries in IntelliJ so I invalidated the caches which did not owrk so I ended up manually removing it from my project. The issue still persisted.
- I did many google searches but could not find anything related to this.
- I reviewed these 7 points ChatGPT brought up that could help solve the issue:

1. Check that ExampleRestClient is annotated with @RegisterRestClient and that the correct base URL is provided in the annotation.
2. Ensure that the ExampleRestClient interface and its dependencies are correctly defined in your pom.xml file.
3. Check that ExampleRestClient has a default no-arg constructor or that all of its dependencies are also correctly defined as injectable beans.
4. Make sure that the BookService is annotated with @ApplicationScoped or another appropriate CDI scope.
5. Ensure that all dependencies of BookService are also correctly defined and annotated as injectable beans.
6. Verify that any configuration properties required by ExampleRestClient or BookService are correctly defined in your application configuration.
7. If the problem persists, review any additional error messages or stack traces provided for more information on the root cause of the injection failure.

I have looked through all of these to the best of my abilities, with no luck.

Comment: I couldn't replicate the issue using your code. If you could upload a sample project to GitHub, it would be easier for someone to provide assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved.

I was missing a GET annotation on one of the RestClient routes. Uh oh.